# How to add the hidden div above another div?

Tags: html, jquery, css

### Situation:

At the top I have a `navbar` and then a `carousel`.
**navbar code**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand order-0 nav-link" href="#">DASA</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right order-lg-0 order-last" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link menWomenKidsHeading" href="#">MEN <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link menWomenKidsHeading" href="#">WOMEN</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link menWomenKidsHeading" href="#">KIDS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search "></i></a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user "></i></a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag "></i></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="">
      <i class="fas fa-bars hamburger"></i>
    </span>
  </button>
</nav>
```

**Carousel code**

```
    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions1" class="carousel slide like" data-ride="carousel like">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <!-- first item RED ANCHARA -->
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/IMG_2124.JPG);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">
          ANCHARA WITH RED BOUTIQUE
        </h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          SHOP ANCHARA
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- second item KIDS -->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/group.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">ANCHARA FOR KIDS</h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          SHOP KIDS
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- third item MULTI-COLOR ANCHARA-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/anchara1.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">MULTI-COLOR ANCHARA</h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          SHOP WOMEN
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fourth item dHOTI-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/hrithik.JPG);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">MARRIAGE DHOTI</h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          SHOP DHOTI
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fifth item CUSTOMIZE YOUR CLOTHES-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/20190910_120902.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">STYLE YOUR CLOTHES</h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          CUSTOMIZE NOW
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions1" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

### I want:

A hidden div above the carousel and when a user hover over the navbar, it should appear above the carousel with colored div.
**How can I achieve this using html, css and jq?**  but feel free to give any suggestion.
Please refer to this code ply code.
https://www.codeply.com/p/Mqp1NSjuMz

Comment: It would be great if you can add your code in jsfiddle and share it here so that developers quickly look at it, fix it and provide you the same.

Comment: please wait some minutes I am on it

Comment: https://www.codeply.com/p/Mqp1NSjuMz 
Please refer to this code ply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sounds of it, your carousel is directly after the nav.  If this is the case, you can just use an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) in css, no need for js:

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

.nav:hover+.carousel .hidden {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">nav bar</div>

<div class="carousel">
  <div class="hidden">hidden div</div>carousel
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks 
but what I want is, it should not push the carousel down, it should appear above carousel

Comment: Do you mean on top of the carousel? Covering part of the carousel?

Comment: Yes, covering part of the carousel

Comment: @AmanChaudhary, you can put the div inside the carousel and absolutely position it - see above edit

Answer (score 0):

You can make this with jQuery. The following has a `div` this currently hides, but makes it appear as soon the user's mouse hovers over the `.navbar`.

```js
$(".navbar").hover(
  function() {
    $("#colored-div").show();
  },
  function() {
    $("#colored-div").hide();
  }
);
```

```css
#colored-div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--**navbar code**-->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand order-0 nav-link" href="#">DASA</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-right order-lg-0 order-last" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link menWomenKidsHeading" href="#">MEN <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link menWomenKidsHeading" href="#">WOMEN</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link menWomenKidsHeading" href="#">KIDS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-search "></i></a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user "></i></a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag "></i></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="">
      <i class="fas fa-bars hamburger"></i>
    </span>
  </button>
</nav>
<!--**colored div**-->

<div id="colored-div"></div>

<!--**Carousel code**-->

    <div id="carouselExampleCaptions1" class="carousel slide like" data-ride="carousel like">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleCaptions1" data-slide-to="4"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <!-- first item RED ANCHARA -->
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/IMG_2124.JPG);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">
          ANCHARA WITH RED BOUTIQUE
        </h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          SHOP ANCHARA
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- second item KIDS -->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/group.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">ANCHARA FOR KIDS</h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          SHOP KIDS
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- third item MULTI-COLOR ANCHARA-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/anchara1.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">MULTI-COLOR ANCHARA</h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          SHOP WOMEN
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fourth item dHOTI-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/hrithik.JPG);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">MARRIAGE DHOTI</h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          SHOP DHOTI
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fifth item CUSTOMIZE YOUR CLOTHES-->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <div class="firstBanner" style="background-image: url(images/20190910_120902.jpg);"></div>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
        <h4 class="headingClothShortDescription">STYLE YOUR CLOTHES</h4>
        <button type="button" name="button" class="carousel-button">
          CUSTOMIZE NOW
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleCaptions1" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleCaptions1" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but div should appear above carousel. And @Pete answer worked.